# Android studio cannot detect my device

Tags: android, android-studio

I followed this instruction to install adb for my device http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

However, once I did step 7 and 8, there's an error dialog saying **"The folder you specified doesn't contain a compatible software driver for your device. If the folder contains a driver, make sure it is designed to work with Windows for 64-bit systems."**

I develop on windows 8 machine, and have spent a great amount of time for this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks a ton.

Comment: What android device are you using ?

Comment: I use LG leon LTE. It runs on android 5.1

Comment: can you access your phones internal memory (Pictures,Documents,etc )?